# Download HTML Text with Ruby

Tags: html, ruby

I am trying to create a histogram of the letters (a,b,c,etc..) on a specified web page. I plan to make the histogram itself using a hash. However, I am having a bit of a problem actually getting the HTML.

My current code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby


require 'net/http'
require 'open-uri'


# This will be the hash used to store the
# histogram.
histogram = Hash.new(0)

def open(url)
    Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(url))
end

page_content = open('_insert_webpage_here')

page_content.each do |i|
    puts i
end
```

This does a good job of getting the HTML. However, it gets it all. For www.stackoverflow.com it gives me:

```
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="http://stackoverflow.com/">here</a></body>
```

Pretending that it was the right page, I don't want the html tags. I'm just trying to get `Object Moved` and `This document may be found here`.

Is there any reasonably easy way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505104/html-to-plain-text-with-ruby

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505104/html-to-plain-text-with-ruby

Comment: I should have added without nokogiri. I am running it from my school's server which doesn't have it installed for me to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `require 'open-uri'`, you don't need to redefine `open` with Net::HTTP.

```
require 'open-uri'

page_content = open('http://www.stackoverflow.com').read

histogram = {}
page_content.each_char do |c|
  histogram[c] ||= 0
  histogram[c] += 1
end
```

Note: this does not strip out `<tags>` within the HTML document, so `<html><body>x!</body></html>` will have `{ '<' => 4, 'h' => 2, 't' => 2, ... }` instead of `{ 'x' => 1, '!' => 1 }`. To remove the tags, you can use something like Nokogiri (which you said was not available), or some sort of regular expression (such as the one in [Dru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10422238/234944)).

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to Ruby though, and I was wondering if you could explain what the `||= 0` part is doing?

Comment: Say the first character is `'h'` for hello. The `||= 0` part will check if `histogram['h']` has been set, and if not, it will initialize it to 0. It is the same as executing `histogram['h'] = histogram['h'] || 0`. Initializing `histogram = Hash.new(0)` should work, but sometimes I have issues with it.

Answer (score 1):

See the section "Following Redirection" on the Net::HTTP Documentation [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Net/HTTP)

Answer (score 1):

Stripping html tags without Nokogiri

```
puts page_content.gsub(/<\/?[^>]*>/, "")
```

http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/615