# Convert HTML to a proper plain text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, html-to-text

is there any way I can convert HTML into proper plain text? I tried everything from raw to sanitize and even the Mail gem with it's text_part method which is supposed to do exactly that but doesn't work for me.

My best shot so far was `strip_tags(strip_links(resource.body))` but `<p>`, `<ul>` etc. were not correctly converted.

This is more or less what I have in HTML:

```
Hello

This is some text. Blah blah blah.

Address:
John Doe
10 ABC Street
Whatever City

New Features
- Feature A
- Feature B
- Feature C
Check this out: http://www.google.com

Best,
Admin
```

which converts to something like

```
Hello
This is some text. Blah blah blah.
Address: John Doe 10 ABC Street Whatever City

New Features Feature A Feature B Feature C
Check this out: http://www.google.com

Best, Admin
```

Any idea?

Comment: try this `require 'rubygems' require 'nokogiri'puts Nokogiri::HTML(my_html).text`

Comment: Unfortunately the same result, however I found a solution. Will post here soon!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML to Plain Text with Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505104/html-to-plain-text-with-ruby)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the solution here: https://github.com/alexdunae/premailer/blob/master/lib/premailer/html_to_plain_text.rb

Works like a charm!

Comment: Works quite well except if you have tables: no blank separation between cell contents

Comment: note that it parses html with regex H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ

Answer (score 22):

Rails 4.2.1 has `#strip_tags`, a built-in method especially for stripping HTML tags.

Some examples:

```
strip_tags("Strip <i>these</i> tags!")
```

=> Strip these tags!

```
strip_tags("<b>Bold</b> no more!  <a href='more.html'>See more here</a>...")
```

=> Bold no more!  See more here...

```
strip_tags("<div id='top-bar'>Welcome to my website!</div>")
```

=> Welcome to my website!

Check it out in the [API docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper/strip_tags).

Comment: In order to test the above samples in a console, you'll have to include the helper by issuing the following command in a console: `include ActionView::Helpers::SanitizeHelper`

Comment: This does not take care of things like `&nbsp;` that most WYSIWYG editors seem to use.

Comment: You can easily remove `\n` with `split.join`. Here is what I use outside of a view `ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(response.body).split.join' '`

Comment: [html_to_plain_text](https://rubygems.org/gems/html_to_plain_text) works better

Comment: With this solution HTML entities are not converted to text...