# Extract Substring Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Assume that I have a string which contains,

> Some content blah blah blah
>      Some more random content
>      ParentID: Here goes the important content

I am trying to write a regex in ruby, to parse the value of "ParentID:" out of this string, this is what I have now,

```
def parseForParent(textForParsing)

  string1 = textForParsing.match(/ParentID:([^\/.]*)\n$/)

end
```

This problem seems to be resolved now, check for answers below, I am trying to modify the regex so that I can limit the text that is actually related to 'ParentID'. One way of doing it is to strip all further text beyond a delimiter, or I could incorporate it in my regex.

Comment: What happens if you remove the last `\n`?

Comment: That error means you're not passing what you think you're passing to to `parseForParent`. Are you sure you're calling the code correctly?

Comment: `textForParsing.match(/ParentID:(.*)$/)[1]` just works

Comment: For future reference, you might want to try http://rubular.com/ to test regexes.

Comment: I'm almost positive that `[^\/.]*` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is this using [**`str[regexp, capture]`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)?

```
text = <<END
Some content blah blah blah
Some more random content
ParentID: Here goes the important content
END

text[/ParentID:(?<match>.*)/,"match"]
# => " Here goes the important content"
```

Comment: I am still getting the same undefined method [] error in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You must be doing something odd because it works, though I've made some changes here to make it more Ruby styled:

```
def parse_for_parent(text)
  match = text.match(/ParentID:([^\/.]*?)\n$/)

  match and match[1]
end

text = <<END
Some content blah blah blah
Some more random content
ParentID: Here goes the important content
END

parse_for_parent(text)
# => " Here goes the important content"
```

As a note, method names in Ruby are defined with underscores. Class names are mixed case. Constants are all-caps.

Comment: I am stil getting the same  undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass, is it because the function is returning nil? It is still not extracting the substring.

Comment: @RohanDalvi: Insert `puts textForParsing.inspect` before the match line. You will see that the value you are passing to the method is `nil`. Are you by any chance reading the string from a file? The read might be incomplete. (Hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545068/what-are-all-the-common-ways-to-read-a-file-in-ruby)

Comment: @kristinalim
You are right, that was the problem. Now, the issue is with the regex, so for example, I am getting this output:

ParentID: Transactional NAS <br /><br /> Acceptance Criteria:  <br /><br /> I can verify that after changing 

Ideally, the output should have ended by the end of NAS since there is a <br> tag ahead but it prints everything, so maybe I should use a regex that stops at all "<br>"tags

Comment: Posted an answer. Kindly update your question to reflect the new details.

Comment: Your regular expression needs to be adjusted to avoid those problems. You didn't have any HTML in your example.

Comment: It's the `\n` at the end of the regex. That forces it to pick up everything up to the last `\n` (because it's greedy)

Comment: @pguardiario That's probably it. The original expression worked in my test here, but I've adjusted it.

Answer (score 0):

If all you are dealing with are BR HTML tags, you can simplify parsing by replacing the BR tags in your input into plain text newlines before feeding it into your `parseForParent` method:

```
converted_text = text.gsub(/<br\s*\/?>/i, "\n")
```

That should be flexible enough to handle `<BR>`, `<br/>`, and `<br />`.

**Update:**

As @tadman emphasized, it is generally safer to use a full-blown HTML parser (e.g. [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org)) to handle parsing. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505104/html-to-plain-text-with-ruby) might also be of interest to you.

Comment: This would be better done with a proper HTML parser like Nokogiri. Regular expressions can only pretend to understand HTML tags.

Comment: @kristinalim I can't use "\n" instead of "<br />" because I am feeding this in the form of a csv to a system and that system doesn't format "\n" only "<br />"